# mylatex.ltx and a file name with an umlaut and / or spaces

Tags: unicode, bash, mylatexformat

I'm producing lots of documents by using a template engine (jinja2), a python script (courtesy of a helpful soul) and a template, which is a tex file.

Compiling 50 documents takes some minutes and compiling them twice is a nuisance.

So I've been looking for a way to get mylatex.ltx or mylatexformat.ltx working.

Unfortunately I can't avoid tex files with an umlaut in the filename .

Call this file here "Bär.tex". I'm on a fairly recent Linux.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Es irrt der Menshc \dots
\end{document}
```

If I try to produce a format, it doesn't work:

```
pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" "mylatex.ltx" Bär.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mylatex/mylatex.ltx
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-12>)
! I can't find file `B'.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
<*> &pdflatex mylatex.ltx Bä
                             r.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: Bär.tex
```

No, it doesn't help to modify the command to "Bär.tex", same error. And `\include{Bär.tex}` neither.

If I type then `Bär.tex`, pdflatex is happy, but I can't go and type all the file names during a run, because there are many with umlaut and / or a space in the name.

Any ideas? -- Thank you!

Comment: unicode filenames are surprising tricky still, latex goes to some effort to allow the filename to be read verbatim while still allowing other commands  on the commandline. Try using `\input{\detokenize{Bär.tex}}`  (`\include` could not work on the commandline even for ascii filenames)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" "mylatex.ltx" \\input{\\detokenize{Bär.tex}}` worked. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, but the next step suffers from the same issue: `for i in *.tex; do pdflatex "&mylatex" "$i"; done
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=mylatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `B�r.tex'.
<*> &mylatex Bär.tex
                     
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<*> &mylatex Bär.tex
 `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm trying variants of this: `for i in *.tex; do pdflatex "&mylatex" \input{\detokenize{$i}}; done
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=mylatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `input{detokenize{B�r.tex}}'.
<*> &mylatex input{detokenize{Bär.tex}}
 `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, `pdflatex Bär.tex` works out of the box and all other variants I could think of either end with `Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of ^^M.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> &mylatex \
              detokenize{Bär.tex}
` or `! I can't find file `B�r.tex'.

Comment: sorry this is harder than it should be, if you don't give a simple filename the preamble skipping kicks in....  later....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle answered in a comment, I can produce a format with

```
pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" "mylatex.ltx" \\input{\\detokenize{Bär.tex}}
```

on the bash in a Linux environment.

This answer has lead to the next question: how to run `pdflatex "&mylatex" Bär.tex`? See here: [Running pdftex in a »for loop« over many *.tex files, using a format, and hitting file names with umlaut and / or spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/631433/4736)