# Running pdftex in a »for loop« over many *.tex files, using a format, and hitting file names with umlaut and / or spaces

Tags: texlive, unicode, loops, linux, format-files

This is a follow up to this question: [mylatex.ltx and a file name with an umlaut and / or spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631273/mylatex-ltx-and-a-file-name-with-an-umlaut-and-or-spaces)

I'm producing 50 *.tex files by using a template engine (jinja2), a python script, a *.csv file with data and a template. I'm under a recent Linux and using texlive 2021, which is up-to-date.

Compiling the 50 *.tex files, which are in a folder, seems a one-liner:

```
for i in *.tex; do pdflatex "$i"; done
```

I need to compile them twice and that takes a lot of time. So I had the unfortunate idea to preproduce a format, e.g. with mylatex.ltx, like this:

```
pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" "mylatex.ltx" foo.tex
```

Which would have worked, if I hadn't started with a file containing an umlaut:

```
pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" "mylatex.ltx" Bär.tex
```

The solution, by David Carlisle was this:

```
pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" "mylatex.ltx" \\input{\\detokenize{Bär.tex}}
```

However, I got the format file, placed it into the folder with all the *.tex files and tried to run:

```
for i in *.tex; do pdflatex "&mylatex" "$i"; done
```

That doesn't work at all, regardless what I try. I get mainly error messages like:

```
for i in *.tex; do pdflatex "&mylatex" \input{\detokenize{$i}}; done 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded  
format=mylatex)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode ! I can't find 
file input{detokenize{B�r.tex}}
```

To test, simply take any *.tex file and rename it e.g. to `Bär.tex`. As a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Es irrt der Menshc \dots
\end{document}
```

Put Bär.tex into an empty folder, produce the format and then try the loop.

(*EDIT*:)
Running `pdflatex "&mylatex" Bär.tex` neither works!

**QUESTION:**

Can somebody provide a kind of shell / python / whatever file or command to run under Linux with a for loop making `pdflatex "&mylatex" *.tex` compile all the *.tex files in a given folder, even if the file names contain an umlaut and/or a space and using the format file?

A first step would be to get `pdflatex "&mylatex" Bär.tex` working.

By the way: mylatexformat.ltx didn't work neither.

Comment: the problems here are specific to mylatex based formats as if you put anything other than plain chracters on the commandline the "skip the preamble" code kicks in and the expression isn't evaluated as intended. I think it would need some changes to mylatex.ltx but I ran out of time yesterday the issue isn't with the looping, i couldn't get a single file to work. so I'm surprised you said you got that to work, I'll try later,

Comment: A different approach for better performance: [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) can be used to parallelize the compile jobs instead of compiling the 50 jobs in series.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right! `pdflatex "&mylatex" Bär.tex` doesn't work, same error! I changed my question text.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek bash would do them  in parallel if you add a `&` but the main issue is you can't do _any_ one of the jobs, the loop is just standard shell scripting.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This is a great solution: `parallel pdflatex ::: *.tex` compiles all 50 files within 14 seconds! Of course, this isn't of any help for the issue David found, but I even prefer parallel, because producing the format takes time as well!

Comment: You could as well detect in your script that the file names contain umlauts, compile with a temporary name, and change the name back after the fact.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm a user and my knowledge about scripts is too limited. Parallel solves my real issue, what remains is the finding that mylatex.ltx and unicode need to become friends...